# Check if you have already logged in to php

Tags: php

On the login page, would I run a check and if the session with username is already open, postponed to logout and can i do it? How do I change

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("location:../index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: What's not working with your current approach?

Comment: I tried to log in from a fixed pc and 3G cellphone, so with two different ips and both ips, it allows me to login, I would like if a device is already connected, to the new login attempt, close The session is already open and opens a new one so you do not have two devices connected at the same time but you do not know how to do it synchronously